# PDF in iframe showing title as 'Anonymous'

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, iframe

I am using Angular2. I am getting PDF response as BLOB from backend API. The PDF is showing fine in iframe but it is showing title as 'anonymous'. Can someone please guide?

html code:

```
<iframe id="showPDFIframe" allowtransparency="false" title="TestPDF" width="100%" height="800" [attr.src]="dataLocalUrl" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
```

pdf.component.ts

```
    pdfDownload: any;
    protected dataLocalUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
    
    ngOnInit() {
    this.requestOptions = this.createRequestOptions();
    this.requestOptions.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;
    this._pdfModelService.showPDF(this.requestOptions)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      this.pdfDownload = res;
      this.dataLocalUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(res));
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
   }
```

pdfModelService.ts

```
showPDF(options?: RequestOptions): any {
    return this._http.get(this.endpoints.showPDF.uri, options)
      .map( (res) => {
        return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' })
      });
  }
```

See below image 'Anonymous' is showing
[image]

Note: backend API gives the bytes which we cast in BLOB.

Comment: Could you show your response headers?

Answer (score 5):

have you tried providing title in the options:

```
showPDF(options?: RequestOptions): any {
return this._http.get(this.endpoints.showPDF.uri, options)
  .map( (res) => {
    return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf', title: 'testpdf' })
  });
}
```

Comment: No property of BLOB having `title`

Comment: @HassanKashif any other way to work around? Since BlobPropertyBag doesn't have title I forced it as { type: 'application/pdf', title: 'testpdf' } as BlobPropertyBag  but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not certain why the specified title field "TestPDF" in the code is not appearing on the page, the "(anonymous)" value that is displaying could simply be pulling the meta data from the PDF file itself.  A possible solution would be to check the title field in the PDF document properties to set the title there. In Adobe Acrobat, from the file menu select Properties > Description to check/update the title field.

Reference article from W3.org:  https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html